# wrong color mapping in list view android studio

Tags: android

here is my code....

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null){
                view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_adv_item,parent,false);
            }

            Advertisement currAdv = advList.get(position);
            TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_date);
            date.setText(currAdv.getmDate());
            date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_amount);
            name.setText(currAdv.getmAmount() + " at");


            TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
            price.setText(currAdv.getmPrice());



            TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_type);

            if (type.getText().equals("Sell")) {
                type.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                type.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            }

            type.setText(currAdv.getmType());


            return view;
        }
```

Comment: please describe your problem

Comment: You have already asked this question today: you still have `type.setText(currAdv.getmType());` below the `if (type.getText().equals("Sell")) {`, which is wrong

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `"Sell".equals(currAdv.getType())`?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are accessing the editText value before the setText() method. Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
    type.setText(currAdv.getmType());

    if (type.getText().equals("Sell")) {
        type.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        type.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear. If you want to set type color according to Advertisement type, you have to use it's type in if control. Not use textview value.

```
TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_type);

if (currAdv.getmType().equals("Sell")) {
    type.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    type.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
}
type.setText(currAdv.getmType());
```